# How can i randomly select and delete an element from an already existing linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am making a musical chair game. I have made a singly circular linked list now i have to randomly select an element and delete it. How can i do it ?

Comment: Choose a random number, iterate through your list based on the random number selected, then remove such item from the linked list.

Comment: Linked list doesn't support true random access.  Have you considered ArrayList which does support random access?

Comment: Actually this is an assignment

Comment: @FelixMarcus i tried to select the random number through Math.random();  but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Programatically, this should be relatively easy.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;


public class Test
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        Random r = new Random();
        // fill list with random values
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(args[0]); ++i)
            { list.add(r.nextInt()); }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        System.out.println(list);

        // delete some random values
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() / 2; ++i)
        { list.remove(r.nextInt(list.size())); }

        System.out.println(list);   
    }
}
```